# How to delete columns in xlwings?

Tags: python, vba, xlwings

I'm using `xlwings` on Windows (Excel 2007 with Python 2.7) and would like to delete either ranges or columns with `xlwings`. As far as I could see, deletion of a range or a column is a missing feature, so I tried to follow the instructions given [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/missing_features.html) and tried to access the `.Delete` method of Range object in VBA. Do you have any suggestions on what is causing the error and how to delete a range of whole column in `xlwings`?

The code I was trying to run in command line is below (for deleting the whole column in the active workbook):

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Workbook.active()
xw.Range('C1:C3').xl_range.EntireColumn.Delete
```

I received the following error:

```
bound method CDispatch.Delete of <COMObject <unknown>>>
```

`Xlwings` would offer the possibility to clear values from range (by `Range('C1:C3').clear()`), but that would leave an empty range or column to the sheet.

Comment: You're only missing the `()` at the end: `.....Delete()`. Or use the answer of OrangeFlash81.

Comment: @FelixZumstein I tried that but it didn't work on my machine. `xw.Range('C1:C3').xl_range.EntireColumn` would always return a `<COMObject <unknown>>>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access the entire column and then use `.xl_range.Delete()` instead:

```
xw.Range('C:C').xl_range.Delete()
```

Comment: There's no longer an attribute `xl_range`, but you can replace it with `api` now to access the underlying pywin32 syntax ([source](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/missing_features.html))