# xlwings: Delete a col | row from Excel

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlwings

How do I delete a row in Excel?

```
wb = xw.Book('Shipment.xlsx')
wb.sheets['Page1_1'].range('1:1').clear()
```

.clear() works to remove the content. I want to delete the row. I'm surprise the .clear() function works, but not .delete()

Any advice helps! Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/35994514/7889129

Comment: I tried the following and it's not working for me.
    wb.sheets['Page1_1'].range('1:1').xl_range.Delete()

Answer (score 6):

I use xlwings 0.11.7 with Python 3.6.0 on my Windows7.
I do this, and it can work very well :

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import DeleteShiftDirection

app = xw.App()
wb = app.books.open('name.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

# Delete row 2
sht.range('2:2').api.Delete(DeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp) 

# Delete row 2, 3 and 4 
sht.range('2:4').api.Delete(DeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp) 

# Delete Column A
sht.range('A:A').api.Delete(DeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftToLeft)

# Delete Column A, B and C
sht.range('A:C').api.Delete(DeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftToLeft)

wb.save()
app.kill()
```

Comment: You can also do `sht.range('A:A').api.Delete()` (no arguments to Delete())

Answer (score 6):

It is now possible to delete without using `api` property:

```
wb.sheets['Page1_1'].range('1:1').delete()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the *.Rows*, for example:

```
wb.sheets("Page1_1").Rows(1).Delete
```

And you would similarly use the *.Columns* for deleting columns:

```
wb.sheets("Page1_1").Columns(1).Delete
```

Comment: It's showing error message: "Sheet" object has no attribute 'Rows'.

Comment: Are you declearing you "wb"-variable as a WorkBook at the beginning of your macro/script?
Try `Dim wb As Workbook` at the top of your script.
Then instead of your: `wb = xw.Book('Shipment.xlsx')`, use `Set wb = xw.Book('Shipment.xlsx`)

Comment: Miscommunication? It sounds like Prebsus is using VBA directly, while NinjaWarrior is using xlwings.

Comment: @rudolfbyker Indeed, I'm using VBA directly. Being that I answered over 3 years ago, I honestly can't remember whether the `xlwings` and `python-3.x` tags were there when I answered or not...

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(end+1, max_col):

        workbook.sheets[sheet_name].api.Columns(end+1).Delete()
```

I have done this to Delete a certain range of columns, should work with rows too, you just need to keep in mind that the Columns/Rows shift so i just stay at the same column