# Openpyxl to delete Table row in Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm having a bad time figuring out how to delete an entire empty row. When the row is part of an Excel Table.

So I tried with the following code. But it keeps the format of the table and it doesn't work ie for Functions like Count If, because it counts those blank rows.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook as lw

wb = lw(file)
ws = wb['Sheet']

endrow = 10 #target row from which I will delete

#delete entire rows from endrow to the end of the sheet 
for i in range(endrow, ws.max_row + 1): 
    wsRemesas.delete_rows(i)
```

I want those rows to be absolutely blank like the default file. Not part of a table or with format.

Regards.

Comment: You'll need to edit the table.

Comment: @CharlieClark What do you mean? If I use less blank rows in a table then some data gets pasted outside the table range. So I use some Extra Range to paste beforehand  so I then can delete not used range.

Comment: I mean edit the table object.

Comment: Use xlwings to delete the row: An example is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694156/xlwings-delete-a-col-row-from-excel

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution:

```python
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import DeleteShiftDirection

app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = app.books.open('PathtoFile')
sht = wb.sheets['SheetName']

endrow = XX #number of target row from you want to delete below

# Delete after endrow till row 10,000
sht.range(str(endrow)+':10000').api.Delete(DeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp) 

wb.save()
app.kill()
```